# Issue with combining two PHP functions

Tags: php, function, foreach

I'm trying to combine two functions into a single function but I'm having more difficulty than I expected.  I have included the two separate functions and the version where I tried to combine them.  The variable `requestData` holds the object that I'm iterating.  However, in my combined version I keep getting a fatal error of Call to undefined method on the line that has `$this->requestData($value)`.

I feel like I'm missing something simple so apologies for the newbie question.  Thank you in advance for any assistance!

FUNCTION #1:

```
public function iterateRequestKeys($array)
    {
        foreach ($array as $key => $value)
            {
                if (is_object($value))
                    {
                        $this->iterateRequestKeys($value);
                    }
                else
                    {
                        $updated_value = '1234';
                        $array->$key = $updated_value;
                    }   
            }
    }
```

FUNCTION #2:

```
public function requestFindReplace($resourceID, $requestData)
    {
        $this->iterateRequestKeys($requestData);    
    }
```

COMBINED:

```
public function requestFindReplace($resourceID, $requestData)
    {
        foreach ($requestData as $key => $value)
            {
                if (is_object($value))
                    {
                        $this->requestData($value);
                    }
                else
                    {
                        $updated_value = '123';
                        $array->$key = $updated_value;
                    }   
            }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be a few problems here with your combined function. In a nutshell...

1. You're not calling the recursive function and you're not passing the parameters through (line 7)
2. You're not passing by reference either (which I believe you may well need to do with an array, not entirely sure I'm a but rusty on PHP). (line 1)
3. You're attempting to update `$array` which does not exist (line 12)

Try this code instead:

```
public function requestFindReplace($resourceID, &$requestData)
    {
        foreach ($requestData as $key => $value)
            {
                if (is_object($value))
                    {
                        $this->requestFindReplace($resourceID, $value);
                    }
                else
                    {
                        $updated_value = '123';
                        $requestData->$key = $updated_value;
                    }   
            }   
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!  Your code definitely got rid of the fatal error but I think I still have something that isn't quite right.  If the `requestData` object starts out with 5 elements/objects, when I dump the object after the loop, I only get the last object that was in `requestData`.  So somehow I'm replacing with every iteration instead of adding if that makes sense?

Comment: @Jason I don't have PHP at the ready to test this, but could you try removing the `&` from the function line (i.e. line 1). Passing by reference may be the problem, can't recall, it's been a while.

Comment: Thank you for the help!  Turns out your code was working I just just referencing the object incorrectly.  I sincerely appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's you're recursively calling requestFindReplace(), so you'd want to change that to line to `$this->requestFindReplace($resourceID, $value);`

```
public function requestFindReplace($resourceID, $requestData)
{
    foreach ($requestData as $key => $value)
    {
        if (is_object($value))
        {
            $this->requestFindReplace($resourceID, $value);
        }
        else
        {
            $updated_value = '123';
            $array->$key = $updated_value;
        }   
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!  Your code definitely got rid of the fatal error but I think I still have something that isn't quite right.  If the `requestData` object starts out with 5 elements/objects, when I dump the object after the loop, I only get the last object that was in `requestData`.  So somehow I'm replacing with every iteration instead of adding if that makes sense?

Comment: Thank you for the help!  Turns out your code was working I just just referencing the object incorrectly.  I sincerely appreciate it!